# Returning months difference as integer

Tags: php, arrays, function, product

I am trying to return month difference as integer and call if to table column. My code:

```
function ETA($ArrivalDate, $pattern = 'mysql'){


$patterns = array(
    'eu'    => 'd/m/Y',
    'mysql' => 'Y-m-d',
    'us'    => 'm/d/Y',
);
    $CurrentDate = date("Y-m-d");

    $ArrivalDate = $variants_data['ArrivalDate'];

    $diff = $ArrivalDate->diff($CurrentDate);

    return $diff->y;

}
```

The I call it with

```
<td>'.$_GET['ETA'].'</td>
```

But there is nothing returned, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Function scope is your initial problem - $variants_data isn't in scope; you're overriding the $ArrivalDate argument with an undefined value; use a DateTime object for CurrentDate; then if you want months it's $diff->m rather than $diff->y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want in a simpler approach using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object in PHP:

```
function ETA($ArrivalDate){
    $currentDate = new DateTime();
    $arrivalDate = new DateTime($ArrivalDate);
    $interval    = $currentDate->diff($arrivalDate);
    return $interval->format('%m');
}
```

See working example: http://3v4l.org/UlPQo

If you don't pass in an [appropriate format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) $ArrivalDate you will get an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) thrown, so you need to wrap the call in a Try/Catch.

See [DateTime Interval Format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for more on the return value.

Comment: @Budda i've been trying to win but it seems I am not. This code crashed the website
    $currentDate = new DateTime();
    $arrivalDate = new DateTime($ArrivalDate)

Comment: You can check your PHP Version, the DateTime Class was added back in 5.2.0, so we tend to assume everyone has it. Having an old PHP version is perhaps the only thing that might cause a service to crash, otherwise, I'd suggest the server crashing is a separate issue that happened by coincidence.

Comment: You are missing two semi-colons in the above ETA method, and the return format should be "%m" not "m". See http://3v4l.org/UlPQo

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple  one

```
<?php
  //for months
  $monthdiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("d/m/Y")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24*30)));
  //for days
  $daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("d/m/Y")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));

  ?>
```